# Java application running in screen does not terminate with screen quit

Tags: java, linux, bash

I am running a java app that manages other java apps through starting them in different screen sessions. My problem is if one of these managed apps is not responding i'd like to kill its java process through my managing app.

The managing app starts other apps using `screen -dmS appname java -jar path`

The first thing i tried was to make my managing app run `screen -S name -X quit` but most of the time this only eliminates the screen session and i get stuck with a running java app that i have no access to.

The second thing i tried to research is to kill the java process itself which will in return terminate the screen but my problem is how can i get the PID of the java application?

`ps -A` is not helpful because it does not give any clue of the specific java application i want to kill among all others.

I need the PID to be available to my managing application or any other way that gives me the ability to terminate the java process running inside a screen.
However the best thing to solve my problem would be to be able to name the java app process.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30370/how-to-get-the-pid-of-the-last-executed-command-in-shell-script

Comment: Another option is to grep through the output of `jps`.

Comment: grep how? all jps does for me is print the PID and then "jar" how would i identify which PID i need?

Comment: Try `jps | grep "path"`.

Comment: This is highly OS-specific. You could grep ps output first for the screen process based on the appname, get the tty name from the grep, then grep for java processes with the same tty, then kill it.

Comment: How would ps display the appname so i can grep it ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by passing an argument when i start any managed app like so:

`screen -dmS helperApp java -jar path helperApp`

This allowed me to identify the PID of the process among all others by doing

`jps -m | grep helperApp`

And since i now have the PID identified and acquired i was able to kill the process.

Thanks to everyone who helped.